# Rest API em Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Ola, eu tenho uma rotina em C# e estou tentando replicar a mesma em PHP ou no Laravel e a rotina funciona perfeitamente no C#, mas não consigo funcionar no Laravel.

Tanto no PHP quanto no Laravel o erro é o mesmo, que não estou autenticado na API.

Abaixo a rotina em C# que funciona.

```
var Client = new RestClient("https://comercial.cnpj.ws/cnpj/" + CNPJConsulta);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
request.AddHeader("x_api_token", token);
IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request);
var retorno_response = response.StatusCode;
```

Rotina em PHP

```
<?php
$params=['cnpj'=>'00000000000191'];
$header=['x_api_token' => 'token',];
         

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://comercial.cnpj.ws/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$ret = curl_exec($ch);
if ($ret !== false) {
        print $ret;
        curl_close($ch);
        return true;
}
?>
```

Rotina no Laravel

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = new Request('GET', 'https://comercial.cnpj.ws/00000000000191/', ['headers' => 
        [
            'x_api_token'     => 'token',
        ]]);
$client->send($request);

?>
```

Já perdi um caminhão de horas e não consigo achar o erro.

Obrigado

Comment: O teu token é mesmo "token" (a string "token") ou isto é só para exemplo? É que no exemplo em C# que dás tens lá uma variável.

Comment: isso é apenas um exemplo, o token eu passo o meu que autentica

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver o problema, primeiro que tinha um erro no endereço da chamada, mas isso não era o problema principal, pois não estava autenticando mesmo eu ajustando o endereço.

segue o código funcional

```
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$token = '123456';

$res = $client->Request('get', 'https://comercial.cnpj.ws/cnpj/00000000000191/',
['headers'=> ['x_api_token' => $token]]);

$res->getStatusCode();
$response = $res->getBody();
```